# pyodbc sql statement does not accept nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am connecting to SQL database using python. Using pyodbc driver for this. The connection is successful and working fine. My problem is when I write any SQL statement which involves any condition involving nvarchar data type I am getting errors. For example

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = 'my_database_name'')
```

I get following error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
> for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'PDX_database_name'.
> (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")

probably some syntax mistake, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python allows literal strings with `'` or `"`, so the easiest solution is to use `"` in Python and `'` in SQL.  And use the `N` prefix for NVARCHAR literals eg

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = N'my_database_name'")
```

Another really good practice in Python is to use multi-line string literals for SQL queries.  EG

```
sql = '''
select *
from sys.databases
where name = 'my_database_name'
'''
```

In which you don't have to escape `'`, *and* you can cut-and-paste properly-formatted SQL statements of any length.

To us a local variable, replace the SQL literal string with a parameter marker `?`, and pass the variable to the second argument of [cursor.execute](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters)

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = ?'", dbname)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to use a variable to store my database name e.g.

dbname = 'my_database_name'
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = dbname")

would this work?

Answer (score 0):

When you write a string in other string you have to use "" in '' or '' in "".

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = 'my_database_name'");
```