# pyodbc sql - invalid column name

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, special-characters, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to insert some values into a DB.

When I use this line:

```
INSERT INTO <db>.<table>(Country,Name) VALUES ('France' ,"L'OREAL")
```

then I get the error:

```
[SQL Server]Invalid column name 'L'OREAL'. (207)
```

When using the solution recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66823826/pyodbc-sql-statement-does-not-accept-nvarchar):

```
INSERT INTO <db>.<table>(Country,Name) VALUES ('N"France"', 'N"L\'OREAL"')
```

then I get the following error:

```
[SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '')'. (105)
```

Can anyone help how to insert the word "L'Oreal" into db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape it with a single quote. It will now have 2 single quotes; one for the data and one to escape it. It should look like this

```
INSERT INTO <db>.<table>(Country,Name) VALUES ('France' ,'L''OREAL');
```

In Python you can use a replace statement to replace your single quotes with 2 single quotes. The string being inserted into your table needs to be enclosed in single quotes.